# Number of Primitive operations in IF Statement

Tags: algorithm, array-algorithms

I am new to Design and Analysis of Algorithms. I have a nested loop and and if statement.I am unable to determine the primitive operations being done in if statement. The statements are as follows:

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
 for(j=0;j<n;j++)
   if(i!=j and A[i]==A[j])
      duplicate=true
      break;
 if(duplicate)
   break;
```

i am determining the No of operations in if statement as follows:

```
Accessing array element 2 Times
comparing i and J
Comparing A[i] and A[j] 
Comparing AND Operator
```

all this is being done N times. Am i right in guessing the number of primitive operations in if statement? if not then please help me correct this. Thanks

Comment: You should add a language tag, but written this way, the outer loop is only going to run once; that last `break` will exit after the first pass. It doesn't "know" the outcome of the `if` test -- you'd have to check `duplicate` in the outer loop to decide whether to abort the outer loop.

Comment: @McGuireV10 sorry. I forget a  statement. please take a look at the question again.

Comment: I assume the two statements below the first `if` should actually be inside the `if`?

Comment: That's why I was asking what the language should be. Though it's easy enough to guess with this simple example. But yes, Jamshaid, that's what I was talking about.

Comment: @McGuireV10  though it is easy. but as i told earlier that i am new to analysis, that's why i am confused that how much operations will be done if the i != j gets wrong in this case . or how many to count that if both sides of and are true.

Comment: @Henry you are right. I have updated the Question. will you please tell me the number of primitive operations being done here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, we can't determine how many times this will happen since it depends on the contents of the array. Once a duplicate is found, the whole thing terminates. We'd have to see the complete contents of all of the elements from `A[0]` through `A[n-1]` to provide an exact number.

What you *can* say is that, **at most** (with no duplicates in `A[]`), the *entire* code snippet will run `n`<sup>`2`</sup> times. Consequently, the rest of this assumes no duplicates:

- Comparing `i` and `j`

This comparison will occur `n`<sup>`2`</sup> times (again, assuming no duplicates to `break` the loops).

- Accessing array element 2 times
- Comparing `AND` operator
- Comparing `A[i]` and `A[j]`

These other operations only happen if `i != j` is true, because *most* modern languages "short circuit". When that first condition fails (in other words, when `i` and `j` are the same) the rest of the `if` condition is ignored. The `AND` is never processed, the array elements are not accessed, and the array elements are not compared.

Therefore, these will run `n`<sup>`2`</sup>`-n` times. The `-n` is because each `j` loop will always match the `i` iterator for exactly one value, short circuiting the rest of the `if` condition.

I'm going to just assume a C-like language and correctly format the code as if this were a C# snippet:

```cs
// n and A[] initialized elsewhere
bool duplicate = false;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if(i != j && A[i] == A[j])
        {
            duplicate = true;
            break;
        }    
    }
    if(duplicate)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which one should i use in my analysis then? Either it should be N^2-n or n^2?

Comment: _Both_ apply. As in the answer, the `i != j` comparison is `n^2` but the other three operations are `n^2-n` ... _assuming_ the language short-circuits (this is why we kept asking what language you're using -- but most of them short-circuit so it's a safe assumption).

Comment: So i should use both of the cases and generate separate equations for the complexity of each language which use short circuit technique and which doesn't evaluate short circuit technique?

Comment: You could do that, but it's a technicality, you're _probably_ safe to assume short-circuiting will happen. These days you'd probably only encounter full evaluation in things like very simple custom scripting languages. But without short-circuit, all operations would be `n^2`.

Comment: okay. what about the if(duplicate) statement? Will it run n times as it is not the part of inner loop?

Comment: Correct. (Again, assuming no duplicates cause the looping to stop.)

Comment: please look at this [picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z4LEHmJX78G6rGKq2iBzuppX3qUD9F00/view?usp=sharing) and tell whether it is correct or not?

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with whatever that notation is trying to achieve.